# Code::Blocks, Clang, C++, Windows 10, не может найти windows.obj

Tags: c++, c++14, codeblocks, clang

Пытаюсь сделать GUI для своей программы. Переключил тип с Console на GUI. Пишет, что не может найти windows.obj во время сборки. Добавлял `#include <windows.h>`, ничего не изменилось.

Версии инструментов последние, не ночнушки. Стандарт C++ - 14.

Comment: Clang почему-то игнорирует параметр subsystem

Comment: С нуля создайте гуй проект, там будут включены необходимые библиотеки.

Comment: С Clang то же самое. Создал гуй проект. Опять жалуется на windows.obj.

Comment: Тогда хуже, надо изучать пути установки SDK clang и корректно их прописать в Code::Blocks. Так-же можно найти где живет windows.obj в директориях clang и прописать его вместе с путем в linker Path в настройках проекта.